# Recovering pose from essential matrix gives inconsistent sign of translation vector

Tags: c++, eigen, 3d-reconstruction, multiple-views, projective-geometry

I have three views with point correspondences and I want to compute the pose of the camera at the second and the third view. I therefore generate a random dataset (no noise) containing points in the different views with known rotation and translation of the camera at second and third view with respect to the first view. I first generate random 2D points in the first view, then I assign random (positive) depths to obtain the corresponding 3D points and finally use randomly generated rotations and translations to project these 3D points into the second and third view.

First, I compute the trifocal tensor (see Hartley & Zisserman, Multiple View Geometry Chapter 15). Then I follow the approach that is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21834667/4238547) to obtain the rotations `R_i` and the translations `t_i` of the second and third view.

The calculation always yields the correct rotation, but unfortunately, the sign of the translation vectors is not always correct. `t2`and `t3` have the correct scale, **but it happens sometimes (!)**, when I use a new randomly generated dataset, **that the sign is inverted with respect to the ground truth translations**, e.g.:

Ground truth:

```
R2 = [0.9942   -0.0998    0.0393
      0.1069    0.9541   -0.2798
     -0.0096    0.2823    0.9593]
t2 = [0.4267
      0.3747
      0.3544]
R3 = [0.9764   -0.0626    0.2069
      0.1358    0.9222   -0.3622
      -0.1681    0.3817    0.9089]
t3 = [0.3963
      0.0285
      0.2093]
```

Output of my algorithm (with translation determined up-to-scale):

```
R2 = [0.994229 -0.0998196  0.0393062
      0.106851   0.954105  -0.279761
     -0.00957664   0.282346   0.959265]
t2 = [-0.637428
      -0.559842
      -0.529398]
R3 = [0.976367 -0.0625748   0.206861
      0.135829    0.92217  -0.362151
      -0.168099    0.38169   0.908876]
t3 = [-0.591991
      -0.0426261
      -0.312637]
```

Comparing ground truth and my output of `t2` and `t3`, we see that they are identical up-to-scale (and in this example, inverted by sign), i.e. element-wise division of the translation vectors `t2./t3` (using matlab notation) from ground truth and my algorithm yield:

```
for ground truth:
[ 1.0768
 13.1338
  1.6933]

for my algorithm:
[ 1.0768
 13.1338
  1.6933]
```

**My first question is:
What could possibly be the cause of this inconsistency of the sign of the translation vectors?** (Especially given the fact that the results are correct otherwise).

**My second question is:
Where do these formulas given in the above linked answer, Step 4, come from? I have the book "Multiple View Geometry" by Hartley & Zisserman, but could not find the described algorithm there.**

Here is a code snippet of my implementation of step 4 of the algorithm in the above link (using the Eigen library, I do not want to use OpenCV) for finding the right solution of rotation `R` and translation vector `t` from an essential matrix `E`, given a 3-view homogeneous 2D point correspondence `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`:

```
getPoseFromEssentialMat(Matrix3d E)
{
  Matrix3d W, U, V;
  W << 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0;

  // calculate the SVD of the essential matrix
  JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svdE(E, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
  // if det(U) < 0 -> U = -U, if det(V) < 0 -> V = -V
  U = svdE.matrixU();
  if (U.determinant() < 0.0)
  {
    U *= -1.0;
  }
  V = svdE.matrixV();
  if (V.determinant() < 0.0)
  {
    V *= -1.0;
  }

  R = U * W * V.transpose();
  t = U.col(2);

  findCorrectSolution(R, t, W, U, V);
}


findCorrectSolution(Matrix3d& R, Vector3d& t, Matrix3d W, Matrix3d U, Matrix3d V)
{
  MatrixXd P(3, 4); // P = [R | t]
  P.block(0, 0, 3, 3) = R;
  P.col(3) = t;

  Vector3d Rtpt = R.transpose() * t;
  Matrix3d M = crossProductMatrix(Rtpt);
  Vector3d X_1 = M * K_inv_ * p1; // point in 1. view

  Vector3d X_i = M * R.transpose() * K_inv_ * pi; // point in i. view

  if (X_1(2) * X_i(2) < 0.0) // depth components
  {
    R = U * W.transpose() * V.transpose();
    Rtpt = R.transpose() * t;
    M = crossProductMatrix(Rtpt);
    X_1 = M * K_inv_ * p1;
  }
  if (X_1(2) < 0.0) // depth of 1. 3D point
 {
    t = -t;
 }
```